# Scanning my table c# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

So i'm making a library system, and i encounter a problem in my Borrowing and Returning of books.

When i borrow a book then return it changing the status to return, then borrowing that same book again success, then when i'm returning it my trapping for return books message show.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltransactionbooks WHERE fBarCodeNo LIKE '" + txtBARCODE_R.Text.Trim() + "%'";
cfgotcall.engageQuery(sql);
if (cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fStatus"].ToString().Equals("Borrowed"))
{
    txtTITLE_R.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fBookTitle"].ToString();
    txtAUTHOR_R.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fAuthor"].ToString();
    txtYEAR_R.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fBookYr"].ToString();
    txtACCNO_R.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fAccNo"].ToString();
    txtCALLNO_R.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fCallNo"].ToString();
    txtBARCODE_BR.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fBarcodeNo"].ToString();
    txtSEARCH.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fStudent"].ToString();
    txtReturnDate.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fBorrowDate"].ToString();
    txtIDNO.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fIDStudent"].ToString();
    txtLEVEL.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fLevel"].ToString();
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Book already returned.");
}
```

What i debug in my own code in the pic is it doesn't scan the whole rows in the `tbltransactionbooks` it only reads the `first row` of my table.

```
33  123 NAME    IT  2/20/2017   2/20/2017   [HISTORY OF] COMPUTERS: THE MACHINES WE THINK WITH  Returned
33  123 NAME    IT  2/21/2017   2/21/2017   [HISTORY OF] COMPUTERS: THE MACHINES WE THINK WITH  Borrowed
```

![2]: http://i66.tinypic.com/28ajgwg.jpg

How dow I scan the whole rows in my table? If my code above does not look good I'm open in suggestion of how I am able make it clean. thanks

Comment: You really need to sanitize your inputs.

Comment: sorry my first time here, can't find my problem on google.

Comment: It's not related to your problem, which is answered below (you're only reading from the first row of results).  It's a different problem where you're accidentally giving people the ability to edit your database by directly reading text input into a SQL Query.  Someone can type into the text box `; drop table users; --` and if you've got that table, your database will execute the instruction.

Comment: oh ok, i know what you just said, its a `sql injection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]` refers to the the **first row only**.

You should iterate each row:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltransactionbooks WHERE fBarCodeNo LIKE '" + txtBARCODE_R.Text.Trim() + "%'";
cfgotcall.engageQuery(sql);

foreach(var row in cfgotcall.tbl.Rows)
{
   if (row["fStatus"].ToString().Equals("Borrowed"))
   {
     txtTITLE_R.Text = row["fBookTitle"].ToString();
     txtAUTHOR_R.Text = row["fAuthor"].ToString();
     txtYEAR_R.Text = row["fBookYr"].ToString();
     txtACCNO_R.Text = row["fAccNo"].ToString();
     txtCALLNO_R.Text = row["fCallNo"].ToString();
     txtBARCODE_BR.Text = row["fBarcodeNo"].ToString();
     txtSEARCH.Text = row["fStudent"].ToString();
     txtReturnDate.Text = row["fBorrowDate"].ToString();
     txtIDNO.Text = row["fIDStudent"].ToString();
     txtLEVEL.Text = row["fLevel"].ToString();
   }
   else 
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Book already returned.");
   }
}
```

To avoid getting run time errors due to typos in the column names and the SQL query, you can use [LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx). This way each row is converted to an object and you can access each column by accessing an object property\field.

Answer (score 0):

You are only accessing the first row [0] of the table. You need to itterate through all of them using for or foreach loop.

Side note: I guess this is a homework. It will not do you any good if you find complete solution in the internet. You should rather try to understand how collections/arrays work and how to traverse them using loops.

A couple of tutorials to help you with the task:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288462(v=vs.71).aspx

http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/csharp-collection-tutorial.htm

Comment: sir can you please post some examples on how to iterate through a database using foreach, i'll try to study it. just examples

Comment: The answer from KernelMode below is what you are looking for. 
foreach(var row in cfgotcall.tbl.Rows)...

Comment: yes it's a overdue homework, i agree too it will no do any good for me as a student because what i do now will reflect later on my career. i'm just bad analyzing code and tweaking them

Answer (score 0):

The first row is checked because use access only the first row:

```
if (cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]...)
```

To check all the rows, iterate through the cfgotcall.tbl.Rows collection either using the for or foreach loop.